# Selecting a specific tag in Jquery library

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

i'm working with this `Jquery` library [graphdracula](http://www.graphdracula.net/) and i have this view :

[image: view]

the html code [code](http://pastebin.com/ydyMQgrQ)

```
 <script>
         $.fn.changeElementType = function (newType) {
             var attrs = {};

             $.each(this[0].attributes, function (idx, attr) {
                 attrs[attr.nodeName] = attr.nodeValue;
             });

             this.replaceWith(function () {
                 return $("<" + newType + "/>", attrs).append($(this).contents());
             });
         };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#canvas").changeElementType("a");
        // Now you probably want to add an href
        $('a').attr('href', 'http://www.google.com');
    });
    </script>
```

i'd like to select only the titles ( F2, la fonction une...) not the hole `div` element . i tried:

```
$("text").changeElementType("a");
```

and

```
$("tspan").changeElementType("a");
```

but i had this view (without graph) .

[image: error]

So what is the reasons of this error? How can i fix my code to select the labels and change it to a hypertext link?

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Can you post the HTML after it's been graphed?

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct jsfiddle link? It doesn't have anything related to this question.

Comment: @Barmar sorry I was wrong in putting link i updated it :)

Comment: I'll repeat the earlier question: What ever are you getting?

Comment: That doesn't look like a jQuery error. I don't know what it is.

Comment: That's coming from your HTML: `<h2 class="title">Vue globale du projet : Cot </h2>`

Comment: this is the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined Edit_Project?id_project=1:96
$.fn.changeElementType Edit_Project?id_project=1:96
(anonymous function) Edit_Project?id_project=1:107
n jquery3.js:2
o.fireWith jquery3.js:2
e.extend.ready jquery3.js:2
c.addEventListener.B`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39507/discussion-between-lamloumi-and-barmar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
$("#canvas tspan:contains(la fonction une)").changeElementType("a");
```